# What is the locus such that any vector from it has a given dot product with the given vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Consider a given vector $a$ and scalar $d$. What is the set $X$ such that for any $x \in X$ their dot product equals $d$ : $\forall x \in X: x \cdot a = d$ ?

Comment: It's the unique hyperplane orthogonal to a and passing through a * d/|a|^2 (assuming your vectors are real).

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: What is meant by "a*d" ?

Comment: the scalar product of $a$ and the scalar $d/|a|^2$.

Comment: Yeah, got it. It describes the intersection point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to write down one point $p = \frac{a * d}{|a|^2}$ in this set.  For any other point $q$, we have $(p - q) \cdot a = 0$, so the set of vectors $p - q$ is precisely the set of vectors orthogonal to $a$.